# Call local Javascript files that from static directory

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm working on a small project using **Nuxt** **JS** and I have some **Javascript** files that I want to call from my **static** directory and I don't know how can I do, for the CSS files I do :

```
css: [
'./static/css/theme/bootstrap.min.css',
'./static/css/theme/bootstrap_limitless.min.css',
'./static/css/theme/layout.min.css',
'./static/css/theme/components.min.css',
'./static/css/theme/colors.min.css',
'./static/css/theme/toastr.css',
'./static/css/theme/override.css',
'./static/css/theme/icons/icomoon/styles.min.css'
],
```

I tried the same thing with javascript using script like that :

```
script: [
    './static/js/test.js'
   ],
```

but it doesn't work since I have my test file in inside `/static/js/`

Comment: `next js` is react, but this is tagged as vue. did you mean `nuxt js`?

Comment: i mean nuxt yeah sorry

Comment: Are you trying to pull the resources on nuxt.config.js or on pages?

Comment: yes between script: []

Comment: Add the script without add the static folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
head: {
titleTemplate: '%s - Project name',
   meta: [...],
   link: [...],
   script: [
      { src: '/js/test.js' } // Without adding static folder
   ]
},
```

Comment: thank you, is there any way to add my script before </body>

Comment: You can create your custom script in plugins folder. eg helpers.js and reference it in nuxt.config.js. [Reference using this link](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/plugins/)

Comment: Meanwhile upvote and mark the solution cause it already answers your question.